# GNU screen: can't connect to display

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using GNU screen on OS X and get this error if I start up / use a screen session remotely:

```
Application initialization failed: couldn't connect to display "localhost:11.0"
Unable to initialize window system.
```

Is there any way to re-establish a terminal session's connection to X?

Comment: That doesn't look like it has anything to do with GNU screen.  `screen` isn't an X application, and it shouldn't be trying to connect to an X display.  Is something in your `.screenrc` trying to run an X application?

Comment: It's probably not directly caused by screen, but it is unique to terminal sessions in screen.  I think it's also unique to OS X.  I think screen sessions started remotely have the wrong display variable set, or something along those lines - mac DISPLAY variables aren't supposed to be human-readable, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen does not reset the DISPLAY environment variable when you connect to a new xsession.

You will need to reset your DISPLAY varaible to the correct value.

It is not a problem specific to osx

See here
https://superuser.com/questions/105954/updating-screen-session-environment-variables-to-reflect-new-graphical-login